# Create host on .net core to use as Service on Windows with topshelf

Tags: c#, service, console-application, topshelf

I am totally new in the C# world. So I was told to build a Service which I have never done. So I started exploring different possibilities and got stuck to one IamTimCorrey youtuber, the video I followed was [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=y64L-3HKuP0). He made the point that if I start by creating a Console app I could debug it much easier. When I started to create the console, by accident I chose .net core. After following his video the installation of the service did not work.

Then I started to google and found out that it is possible to use .net core as a service but using Topshelf I had to create a host. Which i found [here](https://medium.com/@tocalai/create-windows-service-using-net-core-console-application-dc2f278bbe42). But I had troubles comprehending what was what.

Now to the question, I wonder how I should setup the host using Topshelf? This must be the reason why my service doesn't get installed on my computer.

I use Visual studio 2019 and Topshelf v4.2.1.215,

My code is seperated by a Heartbeat class and Program class.

```
using System;
using Topshelf;
using Topshelf.Builders;

namespace Heartbeat
{
    class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var hostBuilder = new HostBuilder()
            .ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostContext, config) =>
            {
         // Configure application configuration here
         // ....
     })
            .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
            {
         // Configure application service here
       //  services.AddTransient<XXXService>();
         // ...
     });

            var exitCode = HostFactory.Run(x => 
                {
                    x.Service<Heartbeat>(s =>
                    {
                    //Servicen heter Heartbeat.
                        s.ConstructUsing(Heartbeat => new Heartbeat());
                        s.WhenStarted(Heartbeat => Heartbeat.Start());
                        s.WhenStopped(Heartbeat => Heartbeat.Stop());
                    });
                    // Service log on as
                    x.RunAsLocalSystem().StartAutomatically().EnableServiceRecovery(rc => rc.RestartService(1));
                    // Enligt heartbeat som var gjord på .net framework lib.
                    //x.RunAsLocalSystem();
                    x.SetServiceName("HeartbeatService");
                    x.SetDisplayName("Heartbeat Service");
                    x.SetDescription("This is the sample heartbeat service from a console tst from youtube.");
                });

            int exitCodeValue = (int) Convert.ChangeType(exitCode, exitCode.GetTypeCode());
            Environment.ExitCode = exitCodeValue;
        }

    }

}

    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Timers;

namespace Heartbeat
{
    class Heartbeat
    {
        private readonly System.Timers.Timer _timer;

        public Heartbeat()
        {
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000) { AutoReset = true };
            _timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
        }

        private void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            string[] lines = new string[] { DateTime.Now.ToString() };
            File.AppendAllLines(@"C:\Users\73215787\Downloads\Heartbeat.txt", lines);
        }

        public void Start()
        {
            _timer.Start();
        }

        public void Stop()
        {
            _timer.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: .Net core is preferred when you are targeting a cross platform environment. Why would you want to use .Net core when you want to create a *Windows* Service?

Comment: Because I want to reuse the code if for example it would be Linux. It seems to be possible, I just dont get how to be honest.

I tried making the "write" clas as a .net core and the rest in framework but it did not work as intended. That is why I am still exploring this option.

Comment: The problem was that I was missing the SDK on my computer, hence the service refused to be installed. And when I had it, I couldnt install and start in the same line.